# VBA - Method Range of Object_ Worksheet failed

Tags: excel, vba

Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong ? 
Why when I do this it works: `Range("E2:E" & Lrow).copy`
But when I do this `rng.copy` it doesn't ?

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyL()

Dim Lrow As Long
Dim Lcol As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = sht.Range("E2:E" & Lrow)

Lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

rng.Copy

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You are setting `Lrow` after you are trying to use it, instead of beforehand. And that means it has the value of `0` - and there is no Row 0.

Comment: Thanks braX. Makes sense now.